# Getting All OUs from a Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ou

Is there any direct method for getting all OUs coming under in an Active Directory?
I had tried the following code, and i am getting Com Exception (Invalid operation) at

```
ouSearch.FindAll()
```

My code is shown below.

```
public static List<string> GetAllOus(string ldapServer, string ldapUserName, string ldapPassWord)
    {

        List<string> orgUnits = new List<string>();
        string defaultNamingContext;

        DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry(ldapServer + "/dc=server-dc,dc=com", ldapUserName, ldapPassWord, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
        //defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();

        //DirectoryEntry defaultentry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext);

        DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootDSE,
                                             "(objectClass=organizational-Unit)",
                                             null, SearchScope.Subtree);

        foreach (SearchResult resEnt in ouSearch.FindAll())
        {
            string OUName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
            orgUnits.Add(OUName);
        }

        return orgUnits;
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What value does your `ldapServer` have??

Comment: @marc_s: its contains the value like, LDAP://192.168.2.5 (AD Server)

Comment: OK, just make absolutely sure that the `LDAP://` part is **capitalized** (don't use `ldap://` or `Ldap://` or anything like that..)

Comment: I think you should use (objectClass=organizationalUnit) and not (objectClass=organizational-Unit).

Comment: ya.. its fully capitalized.

Comment: Now its getting An operations error occurred (DirectoryServiceCOMexception)

Comment: Did you already try AuthenticationTypes.Secure instead of AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous?

Comment: @Hans: After changing the authenticationType to Secure, i am getting this error. A referral was returned from the server (DirectoryServiceCOMexception)

Comment: @MAC: What's the name of your domain? Is server-dc really your domain name or the name of your domain controller?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30825/discussion-between-mac-and-hans)

Answer (score 2):

use (objectClass=**organizationalUnit**)  instead of  (objectClass=organizational-Unit)